# Mostrar a data selecionada pelo usuário usando MonthCalendar

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso que quando um usuário selecione uma data apareça uma MessageBox dizendo:

> Sua aula foi marcada para [data]

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Proxima Aula Maracada para: " + sender);
     // Eu coloquei esse comando pois ele aparece o que eu quero 
     // porém aparece mais coisas que eu não quero
}
```

Comment: A resposta atende o que foi pedido? Precisa de mais detalhes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você está usando um [`MonthCalendar`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar), poderia fazer o seguinte:

```cs
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    var data = ((MonthCalendar)sender).SelectionStart.ToShortDateString(); 
    MessageBox.Show("Proxima Aula Maracada para: " + data);
}
```

Note que o método [`ToShortDateString()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring) serve para retornar a representação da data em string no formato curto dependendo da cultura, no caso de pt-BR seria `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Também seria possível usar os argumentos do evento:

```cs
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Proxima Aula Maracada para: " + e.Start.ToShortDateString);
}
```

Comment: +1 Valeu LINQ Obrigado